# Removing nan values from a Python List

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

Can someone see why this is not working? I am trying to remove nan values from my python List/array.

```
import math
import numpy as np

def clean_List_nan(List):
    Myarray=np.array(List)
    x = float('nan')
    for elem in Myarray:
        if math.isnan(x):
            x = 0.0
    return Myarray


oldlist =[nan, 19523.3211203121, 19738.4276377355, 19654.8478302742, 119.636737571360, 19712.4329437810, nan, 20052.3645613346, 19846.4815936009, 20041.8676619438, 19921.8126944154, nan, 20030.5073635719]

print(clean_List_nan(oldlist))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The control flow in your function makes no sense - you set a variable `x` to be `nan`, and then check if it is indeed `nan` in your loop and set it to 0. You never touch nor check any of the elements of the array.

To properly convert your `nan` values to 0, you could simply use [`numpy.nan_to_num`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) as it appears you're working with  NumPy arrays.

**Demo**

```
In[37]: arr
Out[37]: 
array([            nan,  19523.32112031,  19738.42763774,  19654.84783027,
          119.63673757,  19712.43294378,             nan,  20052.36456133,
        19846.4815936 ,  20041.86766194,  19921.81269442,             nan,
        20030.50736357])

In[38]: np.nan_to_num(arr)
Out[38]: 
array([     0.        ,  19523.32112031,  19738.42763774,  19654.84783027,
          119.63673757,  19712.43294378,      0.        ,  20052.36456133,
        19846.4815936 ,  20041.86766194,  19921.81269442,      0.        ,
        20030.50736357])
```

---

If you're more interested in having a functioning version of an approach for a regular Python list, you might try something like this, or a list comprehension as fafl has provided.

```
In[39]: list(map(lambda x: 0.0 if math.isnan(x) else x, oldlist))
Out[39]: 
[0.0,
 19523.3211203121,
 19738.4276377355,
 19654.8478302742,
 119.63673757136,
 19712.432943781,
 0.0,
 20052.3645613346,
 19846.4815936009,
 20041.8676619438,
 19921.8126944154,
 0.0,
 20030.5073635719]
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from Mitch is probably the best way to do it. If you wish to write this manually you can do something like

```
cleanlist = [0.0 if math.isnan(x) else x for x in oldlist]
```